# Blender reflects an HDRI that no longer exists in a project and ignores current ones

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri, reflection, roughness

I am using Blender 3.2 and I have project that I started with 2.8 or 2.9 if that matters. I changed the HDRI map but no matter what, when roughness is low, it reflects that old HDRI, it even reflects it when it is physically impossible (in closed room or so). Is it known bug or something? Can I do anything? It is both Eevee and Cycles but I`m in Evee.

Comment: if it was in Eevee only I would say delete the lighting cache but you say that it's the same in Cycles? Maybe pack your images and share your file?

Comment: hm but it actually worked! Thank you

Comment: ...was it showing in _Cycles_ in _Rendered View_ or in the _Material Preview_? Because the _Material Preview_ uses _Eevee_ settings as far as I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have baked the indirect lightings, so the reflections will stay even if you remove the HDRI. To fix it, delete the lighting cache in the *Render* panel:

[image]

Comment: yes it works! thank you! I don`t however think, I tried Light Probe, only heard about it.

Comment: My bad, you don't need a light probe to bake the HDRI, so you must have just baked  ;)

Comment: understood!!!!!